# Can't click enable or show items in Page Editor in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I can't seem to click the "Editing" "Designing" "Controls" "Navigation bar" checkboxes in the View ribbon on the Page Editor. Is this a permission thing? Haven't found a way to enable it (I have it enabled on a mirror/development version so I know it works)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently for anyone checking this out, if you don't have the appropriate item commands in your Commands.config file, then they will neither enable or disable these options.

So the solution is to check your Commands.config file and make sure you have the appropriate "webedit:toggleeditvisibility", etc. commands in there.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a permissions thing. See if your user is a member of sitecore\Author and sitecore\Designer, if you're not using a user account marked "Is Administrator"

Comment: yeah this was the first thing I checked. it could have been this as well